# Get all stored procedures that perform a read, update, delete in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a lot of stored procedures that have basic logic such as:

```
if x == 'something' return 10 else return 40;
```

Those stored procedures do not hit any database tables.

How can I find out what stored procedures hit the database?

Note that in some stored procedures, I have other stored procedures that hit the database and not themselves per se.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to know which stored procedures had reference data object of database？ Which the following script is helpful for you

```
    SELECT m.object_id,o.name,c.*,o.type,o.type_desc FROM sys.all_sql_modules AS m
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON o.object_id=m.object_id
    OUTER  APPLY(

        SELECT
          coalesce(object_schema_name(Referencing_ID)+'.','')+ --likely schema name
            object_name(Referencing_ID)+ --definite entity name
            coalesce('.'+col_name(referencing_ID,referencing_minor_id),'')
               AS [referencing],
          coalesce(Referenced_server_name+'.','')+ --possible server name if cross-server
               coalesce(referenced_database_name+'.','')+ --possible database name if cross-database
               coalesce(referenced_schema_name+'.','')+ --likely schema name
               coalesce(referenced_entity_name,'') + --very likely entity name
               coalesce('.'+col_name(referenced_ID,referenced_minor_id),'')AS [referenced]
        FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
        WHERE referencing_id =m.object_id

    ) AS c
    WHERE o.type='P'
    AND c.referencing IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi Nolan, great SQL query! Just to note, for SPs referencing database objects last WHERE cluase condition will be "c.referencing IS NOT NULL"